# chdir not declared, compilation error g++

Tags: compilation, g++, chdir

I am trying to compile a relatively simple application that I obtained from the web..

When running make I get the following error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
os.h: In function ‘void myOpenDir(const char*)’:
os.h:13:16: error: ‘chdir’ was not declared in this scope
```

The file os.h looks like this:

```
#ifndef OS_H
#define OS_H


#if defined(__GNUG__)

#define INT64 long long
#define UINT64 unsigned long long
#include <dirent.h>
#define SPRTR '/'
void myOpenDir(const char* dirpath)
{
    chdir(dirpath);
}

#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
    #define INT64 __int64
    #define UINT64 unsigned __int64
    #include <direct.h>
    #define SPRTR '\\'
    void myOpenDir(const char* dirpath)
    {
        _chdir(dirpath);
    }
        #else
        #error "Platform not supported. Need to update source code"
        #endif 
#endif
```

Someone got an idea why it wont compile?

I also used a g++ compiler via g++-4.7.real -c main.cpp but so far no luck.

Comment: On what operating system are you compiling (and for which target)? You should get the habit of compiling with `g++-4.7 -Wall -g`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `#include <unistd.h>`, as per [the chdir manual](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/chdir.2.html).

Comment: Brilliant thanks! I'll see if this also works in the other applications. In 8 minutes Ill give you 2 thumbs up and check your answer.

Comment: Indeed, BCI2000 has the same issue with the same solution, not documented in their wiki: http://www.bci2000.org/wiki/index.php/Programming_Howto:Quickstart_Guide#Prerequisites_.28Linux.29 Great answer.

Comment: I've played with conditional loads `
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#define chdir _chdir

#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif` but finally i've been forced to add both of them and worked. 

I never spected the mingw to create really cross-platform binarys.